# How to prevent cleveref from picking up the separator in enumerate environments?

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

I am defining a new label class with `cleveref`, which I name "Cases". I also define a custom enumerate environment with `enumitem`. Among other things, I make sure that after the numeral in my list, there is a dot by passing the option `label=\arabic*.`. However, this means that the dot is part of what the command `\cref` displays in its output. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=full-,overfullrule=true]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate{label=\arabic*.,wide=0pt, widest=99,leftmargin=20pt,labelsep=*,topsep=-\parskip,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt}

\crefname{case}{Case}{Cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Whatever fancy text\label[case]{c1}
    \item More fancy text\label[case]{c2}
\end{enumerate}

By \cref{c1}, it must be the case that this text is fancy. By \cref{c2}, it must be the case that this text is twice as fancy.
    
\end{document}
```

See the output here:
[image]

I want to get ride of the dots in "Case 1." and "Case 2." without altering the look of the list environment. I have been checking `enumitem`'s package documentation, but found nothing that could help. Can you help me achieve what I need?

Comment: Add `ref=\arabic*` to the `\setenumerate` declaration

Comment: Thank you very much, @egreg. Substituting `label=\arabic*.` for `ref=\arabic*` did the trick.

Comment: ADDING, not replacing.

Comment: Actually, replacing it did the trick. Why should I add it rather than replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `enumitem` you can separately set the label and the format for references.

```
\setenumerate{
  label=\arabic*.,
  ref=\arabic*,
  wide=0pt,
  widest=99,
  leftmargin=20pt,
  labelsep=*,
  topsep=-\parskip,
  partopsep=0pt,
  parsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt
}
```

Don't just replace `label` with `ref`.

Beware that your lists will look strange if you nest them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Luckily, I do not think I will have nested lists.